# itertools.islice compared to list slice

Tags: python, performance, iteration

I've been trying to apply an algorithm to reduce a python list into a smaller one based on a certain criteria. Due to the large volume of the original list, in the order of 100k elements, I tried to itertools for avoiding multiple memory allocations so I came up with this:

```
reducedVec = [ 'F' if sum( 1 for x in islice(vec, i, i+ratio) if x == 'F' ) 
                         > ratio / 3.0 else 'T'
                for i in xrange(0, len(vec), ratio) ]
```

Execution time for this takes a worryingly long time in the order of a few minutes, when vec has around 100k elements. When I tried instead:

```
reducedVec = [ 'F' if sum( 1 for x in vec[i:i+ratio] if x == 'F' ) 
                         > ratio / 3.0 else 'T'
                for i in xrange(0, len(vec), ratio) ]
```

in essence replace islice with a slice the execution is instantaneous.

Can you think of a plausible explanation for this? I would have thought that avoiding to repeatedly allocate a new list with a substantial number of elements, would actually save me a few computational cycles instead of crippling the whole execution.

Comment: What about using ``vec.count("F", i, i+ratio)`` instead of ``sum( 1 for x in vec[i:i+ratio] if x == 'F' )``? Makes it more readable in my view and probably faster, too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`islice` works with arbitrary iterables. To do this, rather than jumping straight to the nth element, it has to iterate over the first n-1, throwing them away, then yield the ones you want.

Check out the pure Python implementation from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
def islice(iterable, *args):
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2) --> A B
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, 4) --> C D
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, None) --> C D E F G
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 0, None, 2) --> A C E G
    s = slice(*args)
    it = iter(xrange(s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxint, s.step or 1))
    nexti = next(it)
    for i, element in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == nexti:
            yield element
            nexti = next(it)
```

---

Speaking of the itertools documentation, if I was trying to do this operation, I'd probably use the `grouper` recipe. It won't actually save you any memory, but it could if you rewrote it to be lazier, which wouldn't be tough.

```
from __future__ import division

from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

reducedVec = []
for chunk in grouper(ratio, vec):
    if sum(1 for x in chunk if x == 'F') > ratio / 3:
        reducedVec.append('F')
    else:
        reducedVec.append('T')
```

I like using `grouper` to abstract away the consecutive slices and find this code a lot easier to read than the original

Comment: the grouper is a handy function indeed, makes things more readable

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that using `islice()` involves a Python function call for each element of `vec`, while the extended slice notation is understood by the parser and translates directly to CPython calls.